# Swagger ui returns Whitelabel Error

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I used swagger 2.9.2 in my spring boot app.

`localhost:8080/api-docs` works fine.

However, `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` returns `writelabel error`.

`localhost:8080/v2/swagger-ui.html` and `localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html` return the same error. 
I must have missed something simple. Thanks.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Aug 22 10:05:48 CDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

In `build.gradle`, I have dependency of `springfox`.

`compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2")`
`compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2")`

```
swaggerconfig.java 

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig{
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(MyServiceController.class.getPackage().getName()))
                //.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        String description = "Company -  My API";
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("REST API")
                .description(description)
                .version("1.0")
                .build();
    }

MyServiceController.java 

 @ApiOperation(value = "some description",
            response = MyServiceResponse.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "ok"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "not authorized"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "not authenticated"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found"),
            @ApiResponse(code=500, message = "Interval Server Error")
    })
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/component/operation", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    {
        do something        
    }
```

Comment: Could you try `PathSelectors.any()` instead of `PathSelectors.ant("/api/**")` and see if it changes something ?

Comment: @Arnaud  tried, not working. same error

Comment: @toosensitive Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I am using Spring boot 2.1.4, Swagger 2.9.2, I faced the same issue and got resolved by the following:

- It seems that you have the required dependencies so this is not the issue.
- I think the issue that you have to implement WebMvcConfigure and override addResourceHandlers method:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableSwagger2
  public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   // your Docket and ApiInfo methods

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
   registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
   registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
   }
  ```

Just try to add it and Share what happen with you.

Answer (score 0):

Return the Docket bean like below :

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
```

and add `@RestController` annotation above your controller class

Comment: @toosensitive could you please share a GitHub link of your code so that I can check?

Answer (score 0):

```
So if u have correctly written the swaggerConfig code also added the right dependencies and still getting error
The ultimate solution is 
You need to have perfect combination of swagger version and spring boot version

Just change the spring boot and swagger version as below
Check in your pom.xml or gradle build
Spring boot version :- <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
Swagger and Sawgger ur version:- <version>2.2.2</version>

There are other combinations available but that u need to try on trial basis
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and solve with this Docket bean config:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(this.apiInfo());
}
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and got resolved by the following

You can use one dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

- SwaggerConfig class like below :

  ```
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
   }
  }
  ```
- do not use @EnableSwagger2 3.0 version

> http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html